# Is it possible to trace the chain of imports that lead to a particular identifier?

Tags: haskell, ghc

A Haskell package (let's call it package **A**) has stopped compiling for me due to updated dependencies, with an error about an undefined variable. I have access to an old environment of dependencies where the exact same code *does* still compile, so I can open the module in GHCi and use `:info` to track down where it originally came from, which leads me to package **B**.

The trouble is that the now-broken module in **A** does not *directly* import the module from **B** defining this missing identifier; it must have been getting it through another import that re-exports it. But neither **A** nor **B** have changed at all changed between the two environments. So that means that a module in some *third* package **C** must previously have imported and re-exported my the identifier from **B**, to then be imported (possibly via further re-exports) by the broken module in **A**, and **C** has changed between the two environments to no longer re-export the identifier.

Is there some way I can ask GHC or Cabal in the working environment for the full chain of imports that leads to an identifier being in scope, so that I can identify the package **C**? Otherwise I don't know how to narrow down the cause of the problem without manually reviewing all of the (transitive) dependencies of **A** that could plausibly import something from **B**.

Comment: You could use hoogle (maybe a local instance) to search for the name and make a good guess.

Comment: @luqui That solved my immediate problem, thank you! I already had a local hoogle built anyway. Do you know if hoogle would have found the name being re-exported if the whole module was imported and re-exported (which would have meant that the name of the identifier of interest need not appear in the source in either version)? That turned out not to be the case here, but I was worried about it. But if hoogle can report all exported symbols from a module regardless of whether they're explicitly named, then it might be a general solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know a way to ask for the whole chain, but you could use `-ddump-minimal-imports` to ask for the first step in the chain, then iterate.